# Css @mediaquery no se hace responsivo

Tags: css, html5, responsive

estoy comenzando hace 1 mes con Html, Css, Javascript en un curso online. Creo que mi css es malo y/o mis Div son horribles, comparto código, a ver si me pueden indicar los errores. La idea es que los contenedores, textarea, todos ocupen una linea (100%) cuando el ancho de pantalla es menor a 600px (smartphones básicamente). Probe con flex, block, inline. Los width de 100% no son del 100%!!!! No encuentro lo que esta mal. Intente poner el Css pero me dice que es mucho codigo y no me deja publicarlo.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  html {
    color: #00b400;
    font-family: consolas, monospace;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  .titulo {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 1% 0 0.5% 0;
  }
  main {
    color: #00d400;
    border: 5px solid #002200;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #d60000;
  }
  #contenedorImagen {
    display: none;
    border: 5px solid #002200;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url("/web-encriptador-scr/imagenes/encrypt-green-code.png");
    background-position: center;
    transition: all 1s;
  }
  #textarea1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #textarea2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .aclaracion {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #00ab00;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .contenedorBotones {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .contBotonCifrar {
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1% 0 1% 0%;
  }
  .contBotonDescifrar {
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1% 0 1% 0%;
  }
  .contBotonReload {
    display: flex;
    width: 30%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5% 0 0% 0;
    color: #1c5f1c;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="contenedorForm">
    <div class="contenedorTextarea1">
      <textarea name="encriptar" id="textarea1" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Ingrese el texto que desea cifrar o descifrar..." onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || event.charCode == 32 || event.charCode == 164)" min="1" autofocus></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorTextarea2">
      <textarea name="desencriptar" id="textarea2" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Ningun texto fue ingresado, ingrese el texto que desea cifrar o descifrar..." onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || event.charCode == 32 || event.charCode == 164)"
        min="1"></textarea>
      <div id="contenedorImagen">
        <div class="contenedorVacio">
          <div class="textoEnImagen" data-text="Ningun texto ingresado, ingrese su texto...">
            Ningun texto ingresado, ingrese su texto...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aclaracion">
    <p>&Colon; Solo minusculas sin acentos &Colon;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contenedorBotones">
    <div class="botones3">
      <div class="contBotonCifrar">
        <input type="button" class="botonEncriptar" value="Cifrar" onclick="cifrar()" />
      </div>
      <div class="contBotonDescifrar">
        <input type="button" class="botonDesencriptar" value="Descifrar" onclick="descifrar()" />
      </div>
      <div class="contBotonReload">
        <input type="image" src="/web-encriptador-scr/imagenes/reload.png" class="botonReload" value="Rel" onclick="recargar()" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boton">
      <div class="contBotoncopiar">
        <input type="button" class="botonCopiar" value="Copiar" onclick="alPortapapeles()" />
      </div>
      <div id="contBotoncopiado">
        <input type="button" class="botonCopiado" value="¡COPiADO!" onclick="alPortapapeles()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Desarrollado por Sebascraton - 2022</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Se bien en el teléfono. Aunque solo falta arreglar una parte: los botones

Comment: Cada botón tiene su propio contenedor. Te recomiendo que haya un solo contenedor para los botones

Comment: Supongo que en el header tienes el meta name="viewport" y no tengas otros media que puedan cumplir con el with, es decir  bienes un max-width:600pc y por ahí hay uno de m8n-width:600

Comment: Hola, si tengo el viewport, y solo 1 mediaquery. En el celular no me fije, pero en el modo responsivo de chrome se ve mal a menos de 600px